# Why does my motorcycle turn off?

Tags: engine, motorcycle, harley-davidson

My name is Tracy from Dallas and I'm trying to diagnose a strange problem on my bike. Bike: Harley Davidson Street Glide.

My motorcycle turns off while running and it turns off while at a stand still.  I have checked all fuses changes the fuel pump cleaned all cables and it still turns off. It sound like the air turning it off but i don't know where its coming from... Help!!!

Comment: Is there a loose connection in the wiring - try wobbling the wires...

Comment: Does your engine quit or all the electricity fail? When it stops do you have lights?

Comment: Something to do with ignition, most likely the pick up coil.